# Hi, so I'm confuse about nesting the existing input element inside a form element,

Tags: html

This is a practice thing inside freecodecamp.org:

```
    <form action="https://www.freecatphotoapp.com/submit-cat-photo">
      <input text="text" placeholder="Cat Photo URL">
    </form>
```

It says that the existing input element should be nested within a form element.

Comment: Please rephrase your question so it's more clear whatthe problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some strange bug going on with it identifying the indentation in your code.

Replace what you've got with the below, and it should allow you to continue.

```
  <form action="https://www.freecatphotoapp.com/submit-cat-photo">
  <input type="text" placeholder="cat photo URL">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems nothing wrong about what you're doing. Maybe try adding a slash before the more-than sign like so:

```
<input text="text" placeholder="Cat Photo URL"/>
```

If that's still not working try refreshing the page.

Comment: I added it, and still the same man, hard to be new with programming hahah.